# Google Apps Script Create form with file upload

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-apps

I'm in the process of creating a basic form that takes user input via text boxes and drop down list and upon submit will log into a spreadsheet. So far this works fine.  What I would like to add to the form is a "file upload" feature, that allows someone to select the file and upon submitting the form the file is uploaded as the data values from text boxes and drop downs are logged into the spreadsheet.  I've reviewed the following link https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_fileupload but i'm having a hard time inserting / adding the example into the existing doGet function..  Anyone able to help or provide suggestions?  Here is the Google App Script code so far.

**used the following link to base the form on:  https://sites.google.com/site/appsscripttutorial/advanced-examples/insert-data-in-sheet-using-ui-forms*

```
// Script-as-app template.
 var submissionSSKey = 'Spreadsheet Key goes Here';

 function doGet() {
   var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle('Loan Registration Processing');
   var panel = app.createVerticalPanel();
   var grid = app.createGrid(8,2).setId('loanGrid');
   var loanTypeLabel = app.createLabel('Loan Type');
   var loanList = app.createListBox().setName('Loan List').setWidth('120px').setName('LoanType');
   loanList.addItem('Select Option');    
   loanList.addItem('FHA');
  loanList.addItem('Convential');  
  loanList.addItem('VA');
  loanList.addItem('Reverse');
  loanList.addItem('HELOC');
   var borrowerNameLabel = app.createLabel("Borrower's Name");
   var borrowerTextbox = app.createTextBox().setWidth('150px').setName('borrower');
   var loanAmountLabel = app.createLabel('Loan Amount');
   var loanAmountTextbox = app.createTextBox().setWidth('150px').setName('amount');
   var appDateLabel = app.createLabel('Loan Date');
   var appDateTextbox = app.createTextBox().setWidth('150px').setName('date');
   var lienPostition = app.createLabel('Lien Position');
   var lienPos = app.createListBox().setName('Lien Position').setWidth('150px').setName('LienPosition');
  lienPos.addItem('Select Option');     
  lienPos.addItem('1st');
  lienPos.addItem('2nd');
   var propertyType = app.createLabel('Property Type');
   var propType = app.createListBox().setName('Property Type').setWidth('150px').setName('PropertyType');
  propType.addItem('Select Option');
  propType.addItem('1-4');
  propType.addItem('Manufactured');
   var submitButton = app.createButton('Submit'); 

   //Grid layout of items on form
   grid.setWidget(0, 0, loanTypeLabel)
  .setWidget(0, 1, loanList)
  .setWidget(1, 0, borrowerNameLabel)
  .setWidget(1, 1, borrowerTextbox)
  .setWidget(2, 0, loanAmountLabel)
  .setWidget(2, 1, loanAmountTextbox)
  .setWidget(3, 0, appDateLabel)
  .setWidget(3, 1, appDateTextbox)
  .setWidget(4, 0, lienPostition)
  .setWidget(4, 1, lienPos)
  .setWidget(5, 0, propertyType)
  .setWidget(5, 1, propType)
  .setWidget(6, 0, submitButton)

   //Event Handler
   var handler = app.createServerClickHandler('insertInSS');
   handler.addCallbackElement(panel);
   submitButton.addClickHandler(handler);  
   panel.add(grid);
   app.add(panel);
   return app;

 }
 //Function to insert data in the sheet on clicking the submit button
 function insertInSS(e){
   var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
   var LoanType = e.parameter.LoanType;
   var borrower = e.parameter.borrower;
   var amount = e.parameter.amount;
   var date = e.parameter.date;
   var LienPosition = e.parameter.LienPosition;
   var PropertyType = e.parameter.PropertyType;
   //app.getElementById('info').setVisible(true).setStyleAttribute('color','red');

   var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(submissionSSKey).getActiveSheet();
   var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
   var targetRange = sheet.getRange(lastRow+1, 1, 1, 6).setValues([[LoanType,borrower,amount,date,LienPosition,PropertyType]]);
   return app;
 }
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about using a deprecated service UiApp. Related [UiApp has been deprecated. Please use HtmlService instead](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54605042/1595451)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

here is the code properly formatted :

```
// Script-as-app template.
var submissionSSKey = '*************';

function doGet(e) {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle('Loan Registration Processing');
  var panel = app.createFormPanel();
  var grid = app.createGrid(8,2).setId('loanGrid');
  var loanTypeLabel = app.createLabel('Loan Type');
  var loanList = app.createListBox().setName('Loan List').setWidth('120px').setName('LoanType');
      loanList.addItem('Select Option');    
      loanList.addItem('FHA');
      loanList.addItem('Convential');  
      loanList.addItem('VA');
      loanList.addItem('Reverse');
      loanList.addItem('HELOC');
  var borrowerNameLabel = app.createLabel("Borrower's Name");
  var borrowerTextbox = app.createTextBox().setWidth('150px').setName('borrower');
  var loanAmountLabel = app.createLabel('Loan Amount');
  var loanAmountTextbox = app.createTextBox().setWidth('150px').setName('amount');
  var appDateLabel = app.createLabel('Loan Date');
  var appDateTextbox = app.createDateBox().setWidth('150px').setName('date');
  var lienPostition = app.createLabel('Lien Position');
  var lienPos = app.createListBox().setName('Lien Position').setWidth('150px').setName('LienPosition');
      lienPos.addItem('Select Option');     
      lienPos.addItem('1st');
      lienPos.addItem('2nd');
  var propertyType = app.createLabel('Property Type');
  var propType = app.createListBox().setName('Property Type').setWidth('150px').setName('PropertyType');
      propType.addItem('Select Option');
      propType.addItem('1-4');
      propType.addItem('Manufactured');
  var submitButton = app.createSubmitButton('<B>Submit</B>'); 
  var warning = app.createHTML('<B>PLEASE WAIT WHILE DATA IS UPLOADING<B>').setStyleAttribute('background','yellow').setVisible(false)
  //file upload
  var upLoadTypeLabel = app.createLabel('File Upload');
  var upLoad = (app.createFileUpload().setName('thefile'));

  //Grid layout of items on form
  grid.setWidget(0, 0, loanTypeLabel)
      .setWidget(0, 1, loanList)
      .setWidget(1, 0, borrowerNameLabel)
      .setWidget(1, 1, borrowerTextbox)
      .setWidget(2, 0, loanAmountLabel)
      .setWidget(2, 1, loanAmountTextbox)
      .setWidget(3, 0, appDateLabel)
      .setWidget(3, 1, appDateTextbox)
      .setWidget(4, 0, lienPostition)
      .setWidget(4, 1, lienPos)
      .setWidget(5, 0, propertyType)
      .setWidget(5, 1, propType)
      .setWidget(6, 0, upLoadTypeLabel)
      .setWidget(6, 1, upLoad)
      .setWidget(7, 0, submitButton)
      .setWidget(7, 1, warning)

  var cliHandler = app.createClientHandler().forTargets(warning).setVisible(true)
  submitButton.addClickHandler(cliHandler);  
  panel.add(grid);
  app.add(panel);
  return app;

}

 function doPost(e) {
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  var LoanType = e.parameter.LoanType;
  var borrower = e.parameter.borrower;
  var amount = e.parameter.amount;
  var date = e.parameter.date;
  var LienPosition = e.parameter.LienPosition;
  var PropertyType = e.parameter.PropertyType;
  //app.getElementById('info').setVisible(true).setStyleAttribute('color','red');

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(submissionSSKey).getActiveSheet();
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var targetRange = sheet.getRange(lastRow+1, 1, 1, 6).setValues([[LoanType,borrower,amount,date,LienPosition,PropertyType]]);
   // data returned is a blob for FileUpload widget
   var fileBlob = e.parameter.thefile;
   var doc = DocsList.createFile(fileBlob);
   return app
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to put you panel into a formPanel, use a submitButton  and get all your results in a single doPost function. No need to define a handler nor any callbackElement in this context so you should remove them to avoid conflicts.

If you look at the simple example you showed as reference you'll see the structure that has to be adopted for form submission. I know it works the way you did it too but not for file upload...

Here is you working code : I made a few changes... [testable here](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbxK43j2mKbOW-KJ3kHHuYGuTrtjyGXECuGeIp8FPrPPZHbe4tk/exec)

1. changed the textBox for date into a dateBox
2. added an client handler to show a warning while the file is uploading since this can take a while if the file is big ;-)

Sorry, the system is buggy, I cannot format the code properly, I'll make another answer...

Comment: Could you help with an example of the doPost which would handle all submitted data including the file upload?  I've changed the "var panel = app.createVerticalPanel();" to use the FormPanel, but I'm not quite sure on consolidating the event handler into the createSubmitButton to get the file upload and also the data into the specified spreadsheeet.

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out how to get the file upload to attach to the grid and display, allow file selection and submittal of data values to the spreadsheet.  It doesn't upload the select file to my drive.

I'm posting the updated code below.  Any thoughts on why its not posting the file to my drive??

```
// Script-as-app template.
var submissionSSKey = 'Spreadsheet Key';

function doGet(e) {
  var app = UiApp.createApp ication().setTitle('Loan Registration Processing');
  var panel = app.createVerticalPanel();
  var grid = app.createGrid(8,2).setId('loanGrid');
  var loanTypeLabel = app.createLabel('Loan Type');
  var loanList = app.createListBox().setName('Loan List').setWidth('120px').setName('LoanType');
      loanList.addItem('Select Option');    
      loanList.addItem('FHA');
      loanList.addItem('Convential');  
      loanList.addItem('VA');
      loanList.addItem('Reverse');
      loanList.addItem('HELOC');
  var borrowerNameLabel = app.createLabel("Borrower's Name");
  var borrowerTextbox = app.createTextBox().setWidth('150px').setName('borrower');
  var loanAmountLabel = app.createLabel('Loan Amount');
  var loanAmountTextbox = app.createTextBox().setWidth('150px').setName('amount');
  var appDateLabel = app.createLabel('Loan Date');
  var appDateTextbox = app.createTextBox().setWidth('150px').setName('date');
  var lienPostition = app.createLabel('Lien Position');
  var lienPos = app.createListBox().setName('Lien Position').setWidth('150px').setName('LienPosition');
      lienPos.addItem('Select Option');     
      lienPos.addItem('1st');
      lienPos.addItem('2nd');
  var propertyType = app.createLabel('Property Type');
  var propType = app.createListBox().setName('Property Type').setWidth('150px').setName('PropertyType');
      propType.addItem('Select Option');
      propType.addItem('1-4');
      propType.addItem('Manufactured');
  var submitButton = app.createButton('Submit'); 

  //file upload
  var upLoadTypeLabel = app.createLabel('File Upload');
  var upLoad = (app.createFileUpload().setName('thefile'));

  //Grid layout of items on form
  grid.setWidget(0, 0, loanTypeLabel)
      .setWidget(0, 1, loanList)
      .setWidget(1, 0, borrowerNameLabel)
      .setWidget(1, 1, borrowerTextbox)
      .setWidget(2, 0, loanAmountLabel)
      .setWidget(2, 1, loanAmountTextbox)
      .setWidget(3, 0, appDateLabel)
      .setWidget(3, 1, appDateTextbox)
      .setWidget(4, 0, lienPostition)
      .setWidget(4, 1, lienPos)
      .setWidget(5, 0, propertyType)
      .setWidget(5, 1, propType)
      .setWidget(6, 0, upLoadTypeLabel)
      .setWidget(6, 1, upLoad)
      .setWidget(7, 0, submitButton)

  //Event Handler
  var handler = app.createServerClickHandler('insertInSS');
  handler.addCallbackElement(panel);
  submitButton.addClickHandler(handler);  
  panel.add(grid);
  app.add(panel);
  return app;

}
//Function to insert data in the sheet on clicking the submit button
function insertInSS(e){
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  var LoanType = e.parameter.LoanType;
  var borrower = e.parameter.borrower;
  var amount = e.parameter.amount;
  var date = e.parameter.date;
  var LienPosition = e.parameter.LienPosition;
  var PropertyType = e.parameter.PropertyType;
  //app.getElementById('info').setVisible(true).setStyleAttribute('color','red');

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(submissionSSKey).getActiveSheet();
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var targetRange = sheet.getRange(lastRow+1, 1, 1, 6).setValues([[LoanType,borrower,amount,date,LienPosition,PropertyType]]);
  return app;
}

 function doPost(e) {
   // data returned is a blob for FileUpload widget
   var fileBlob = e.parameter.thefile;
   var doc = DocsList.createFile(fileBlob);
 }
```