# How To store Data from a web page stored in local storage to Google Spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, html

I am Developing an web app which requires the data stored in local storage to be uploaded in Google Spreadsheets
when user clicks a link in the web page.
I Absolutely have no idea about this.
please help me , thanks in Advance

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15772283/how-do-i-get-a-dynamic-javascript-array-into-google-spreadsheets

Answer (score 0):

localStorage is a key value pair store. So, access the required data using that key. for example

```
localStorage['user'] = 'avi'
```

Register a click/submit event on the function and whenever user clicks it, access it and send it wherever you want.

```
function magic():
    ...
    ...
    dataToBeSent = localStorage['user']
    uploadToGoogle(dataToBeSent)
    ...
```

something like that. Of course, `uploadToGoogle` doesn't exist and you have to write using Google Spreadsheets API.

Comment: @Paul I don't think with just JS alone it can be done without backend server. Then I am not sure.