# Upload files in Google Form

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-forms

Another user (**[in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15261247/google-apps-script-create-form-with-file-upload)**) posted an apps script that allows you to upload files to Google Drive via a Google Form.

```
// Script-as-app template.
var submissionSSKey = '0AnqSFd3iikE3dFZ6M1JDekJIa1I5UEZIZURGN3hhM3c';

function doGet(e) {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle('Loan Registration Processing');
  var panel = app.createFormPanel();
  var grid = app.createGrid(8,2).setId('loanGrid');
  var loanTypeLabel = app.createLabel('Loan Type');
  var loanList = app.createListBox().setName('Loan List').setWidth('120px').setName('LoanType');
      loanList.addItem('Select Option');    
      loanList.addItem('FHA');
      loanList.addItem('Convential');  
      loanList.addItem('VA');
      loanList.addItem('Reverse');
      loanList.addItem('HELOC');
  var borrowerNameLabel = app.createLabel("Borrower's Name");
  var borrowerTextbox = app.createTextBox().setWidth('150px').setName('borrower');
  var loanAmountLabel = app.createLabel('Loan Amount');
  var loanAmountTextbox = app.createTextBox().setWidth('150px').setName('amount');
  var appDateLabel = app.createLabel('Loan Date');
  var appDateTextbox = app.createDateBox().setWidth('150px').setName('date');
  var lienPostition = app.createLabel('Lien Position');
  var lienPos = app.createListBox().setName('Lien Position').setWidth('150px').setName('LienPosition');
      lienPos.addItem('Select Option');     
      lienPos.addItem('1st');
      lienPos.addItem('2nd');
  var propertyType = app.createLabel('Property Type');
  var propType = app.createListBox().setName('Property Type').setWidth('150px').setName('PropertyType');
      propType.addItem('Select Option');
      propType.addItem('1-4');
      propType.addItem('Manufactured');
  var submitButton = app.createSubmitButton('<B>Submit</B>'); 
  var warning = app.createHTML('<B>PLEASE WAIT WHILE DATA IS UPLOADING<B>').setStyleAttribute('background','yellow').setVisible(false)
  //file upload
  var upLoadTypeLabel = app.createLabel('File Upload');
  var upLoad = (app.createFileUpload().setName('thefile'));

  //Grid layout of items on form
  grid.setWidget(0, 0, loanTypeLabel)
      .setWidget(0, 1, loanList)
      .setWidget(1, 0, borrowerNameLabel)
      .setWidget(1, 1, borrowerTextbox)
      .setWidget(2, 0, loanAmountLabel)
      .setWidget(2, 1, loanAmountTextbox)
      .setWidget(3, 0, appDateLabel)
      .setWidget(3, 1, appDateTextbox)
      .setWidget(4, 0, lienPostition)
      .setWidget(4, 1, lienPos)
      .setWidget(5, 0, propertyType)
      .setWidget(5, 1, propType)
      .setWidget(6, 0, upLoadTypeLabel)
      .setWidget(6, 1, upLoad)
      .setWidget(7, 0, submitButton)
      .setWidget(7, 1, warning)

  var cliHandler = app.createClientHandler().forTargets(warning).setVisible(true)
  submitButton.addClickHandler(cliHandler);  
  panel.add(grid);
  app.add(panel);
  return app;

}

 function doPost(e) {
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  var LoanType = e.parameter.LoanType;
  var borrower = e.parameter.borrower;
  var amount = e.parameter.amount;
  var date = e.parameter.date;
  var LienPosition = e.parameter.LienPosition;
  var PropertyType = e.parameter.PropertyType;
  //app.getElementById('info').setVisible(true).setStyleAttribute('color','red');

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(submissionSSKey).getActiveSheet();
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var targetRange = sheet.getRange(lastRow+1, 1, 1, 6).setValues([[LoanType,borrower,amount,date,LienPosition,PropertyType]]);
   // data returned is a blob for FileUpload widget
   var fileBlob = e.parameter.thefile;
   var doc = DocsList.createFile(fileBlob);
   return app
 }
```

however, when debugging this, I continually run into the error "TypeError: Cannot read property "parameter" from undefined. (line 66)". Why is this?

The apps script was started as a form App Script and the function is to add a file upload button and "successfully uploaded" screen.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: how are you trying to run this script ?

Answer (score 0):

This was covered recently on s.o.
When you call it from the debugger you are passing nothing (undefined) as the function parameter. 
You need to test it live.